# Struggling to extract elements of divtable type from webpage using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting webscrape from footballdb.com to get data related to NFL player injuries for a model I am creating from links such as this: https://www.footballdb.com/transactions/injuries.html?yr=2016&wk=1&type=reg. All the tables on the page are stored in divtable elements, which I am able to get access to, but then I am unable to extract the individual elements I need from each divtable (i.e. player name, injury, wed_status, thurs_status, fri_status, game_status). Does anyone have experience extracting elements from a divtable class before? Below is the code I have thus far.

```
#Set the start web url
path1<-("https://www.footballdb.com/transactions/injuries.html?yr=")


seasons<-c("2016", "2017", "2020")
weeks<-1:17
data<-NULL
for (i in 1:length(seasons)) {
  path2<-paste0(path1,seasons[i])
  
  for (j in 1:length(weeks)) {
    path3<-paste0(path2,"&wk=",j,"&type=reg") 
    URL<-read_html(path3)
    divtables<-html_nodes(URL, ".divtable")
    
    for (k in 1:length(divtables)) {
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a nicer way to generate the required urls but using your loop format, you can generate the urls then use map_dfr to join dataframes from each page into one overarching df. You can grab each "column" using the class name. The "table" has classes that stand in for `tr` (table rows) and `td` (table cells) e.g. `.tr` rather than `tr`, allowing you to select columns to assign into your dataframe. See [css class selectors versus type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). I took the dataframes inside map_dfr idea from @RonakShah [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65274796/6241235).

```
library(purrr)
library(rvest)

path1 <- 'https://www.footballdb.com/transactions/injuries.html?yr='
seasons <- c("2016", "2017", "2020")
weeks <- 1:17
results <- list()
c <- 1

for(s in seq_along(seasons)){
  for(w in seq_along(weeks)){
    c <- c+1
    results[c] <- paste0(path1, seasons[s],"&wk=", as.character(w), "&type=reg")
  }
}

#use `results` for all rather than just `results[1:3]`

result <- map_df(compact(results[1:3]), function(x){ 
  page <- read_html(x)
  data.frame(
    Player = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(1) b') %>% html_text(),
    Injury = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(2)') %>% html_text(),
    Wed = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(3)') %>% html_text(),
    Thu = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(4)') %>% html_text(),
    Fri = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(5)') %>% html_text(),
    GameStatus = page %>% html_nodes('.divtable .td:nth-child(6)') %>% html_text()
  )
  }
)
```